# Textbox binding not working when page has loaded AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set textbox value based on the result of promise values when page has loaded. The values on textbox set only if I click on it and then out of it (just like blur event).

Controller

```
(function() {
    'use strict'
    var newPurchasingCardController = function($scope, $rootScope, $filter, $window, $location, $timeout, requestService) {        

        $scope.actionTitle = "";            
        $scope.gin = "";
        $scope.fullName = "";
        $scope.workEmail = "";
        $scope.msg = "";            

        var getCurrentUserData = function () {

            var dfd = new $.Deferred();
            var queryUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties";
            $.ajax({
                url: queryUrl,
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError,
                cache: false
            });

            function onSuccess(data) {
                dfd.resolve(data);                    
            }

            function onError(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
                dfd.reject(errorMessage);
            }

            return dfd.promise();               
        }            

        var _init = function () {

            $scope.actionTitle = "New Card Request"

            var promise = getCurrentUserData();

            promise.then(function (data) {

                $.each(data.d.UserProfileProperties.results,function(i,property){
                    if(property.Key === "EmployeeNumber")
                    {
                        $scope.gin = property.Value;
                    }

                    if(property.Key === "FirstName")
                    {
                        $scope.fullName = property.Value;
                    } 
                    else if (property.Key === "LastName") {
                        $scope.fullName += " " + property.Value;
                    }

                    if(property.Key === "WorkEmail") {
                        $scope.workEmail = property.Value;
                    }
                    console.log(property.Key+":"+property.Value);               
                });
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("An error has occurred trying to get employee information." + error);
            });
        }

        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event)
        { 
            _init();
        });            
    }

    angular.module('myApp').controller('newPurchasingCardController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$filter', '$window', '$location', '$timeout', 'requestService', createnewPurchasingCardController]);
}());
```

And in the html view I just have

HTML

```
<input ng-model="gin" type="gin" class="form-control" id="gin" placeholder="GIN">
<input ng-model="fullName" type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
<input ng-model="workEmail" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
```

I have tried with viewContentLoaded but not working, what would be a good approach to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: The promises created by jQuery are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `angularjs` with `Jquery` and that causes all the problems.

Use `$http` service for get request : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

```
var getCurrentUserData = function () {

        var queryUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties";
        $http({
            url: queryUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            cache: false
        })
         .then(function(response) {
             $scope.gin = response.data.EmployeeNumber;
             // here set scope variables directly
         })
        .catch(function(response) {
           console.error('error', response.status, response.data);
         })
       .finally(function() {
           console.log("finally ");
        });

}
```